# Save attachment from IMAP on networkdrive

Tags: scripting, imap, mailbox, attachment, cyrus

I'm looking for a solution to save automatically attachments of an e-mail for a specific mailbox on an network drive. Mails are stored on cyrus imap server.

Does anyone know a script or something like this. Maybe there is a way to do this with sieve?!?

I searched on the web, but didn't find anything.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK Sieve (the scripting language Cyrus loves) does not support attachment extraction. What you can do though is that you create a Sieve script which identified the e-mails having attachments (from sender, message size, whatever criteria you'd like to use), and automatically file those messages to some specific IMAP folder, say *TemporaryAttachmentsFolder*.

Then you can put in cron a shell script, which periodically polls that *TemporaryAttachmentsFolder* directory, and extracts the attachments with a tool like [ripmime](http://pldaniels.com/ripmime/) and saves them elsewhere. Or, if you are truly l337, you can replace the traditional cron with [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) and make the extraction happen in real-time.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following script: https://github.com/auino/mail-attachments-archiver, allowing you to store received mails attachments into a specific directory.